# mount a host volume to a container created through Dockerfile

Tags: docker

New to docker, and as per the documentation about [Dockerfile](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#volume), due to portability, it is not allowed to specify a host volume mapping. That is fine, but is there a way to map a host volume (I am in MAC, so say, my home dir `/Users/bsr` to `/data` of ubuntu image) to a linux container. The [documentation](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) of `docker volume` is talking only about `docker run`, but not sure how to add a volume after creating it.

http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 0):

On **Linux** you can simply mount a directory of your host system to a docker container by passing

```
-v /path/to/host/directory:/path/to/container/directory
```

to the docker `run` command.

You can also see it here in the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume

If you are using **boot2docker** things are more complicated. The problem ist that boot2docker runs a little linux vm to start docker. So if you mount the volume as described above you will mount the directory of the little linux vm.

A workaround for this is described in the README of the boot2docker GitHub page using a samba share:

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#folder-sharing

Comment: thanks David. that makes sense, but in the same doc, https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions, it says `/Users`, will be automatically mounted at the location specified:, `/Users`. But, I don't see any. But, if I specify it in run command ` docker run -d -P -v /Users/bsr/web:/usr/local/web --name web ubuntu`, I get access to host folder. so, the question is since `run` create a new container, is it possible to specify the -v on an existing container, and say start with `start`.

Comment: looks like this was in this pull, https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/pull/534, and may not be available boot2docker 1.2. still digging.

Answer (score 0):

the following worked, with the help of @sciutand.

```
git clone https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker.git
 cd boot2docker/
 docker build -t my-boot2docker-img .
 docker run --rm my-boot2docker-img > boot2docker.iso
 boot2docker stop
 mv ~/.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso ~/.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso.backup
 mv boot2docker.iso ~/.boot2docker/boot2docker.iso
 VBoxManage sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm -name /Users -hostpath /Users
 boot2docker up
 docker run -d -P --name web ubuntu
```